# Install Firebird on CentOS7

Tags: centos-7, firebird

I just installed Firebird on my fresh new CentOS 7 installation, but it isn't found by `systemctl`:

```
[root@intranet-ii ~]# yum install firebird
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * epel: ams.edge.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.denit.net
 * updates: mirror.ams1.nl.leaseweb.net
Package firebird-2.5.7.27050.0-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@intranet-ii ~]# systemctl start firebird-superserver
Failed to start firebird-superserver.service: Unit not found.
```

I cannot find where the server is supposed to live, nor can I find any reference on this online.

Comment: Is there a reason why you decided to not install the firebird-superserver package?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no. Didn't even know that package existed. The examples I found didn't mention it.